# How to install new version of freefilesync

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, free-software

I installed Freefilesync a long time ago to be launched via the standard launcher.

I now proposes me to install a new version for Debian 9.2 64 bits or Ubuntu 16.04 64 bits.

I have tried both but it downloads a tar.gz file. I tried to décompress one, It gives me a freefilesync file that does not want to open.

I'm stuck at that point.

All advices would be appreciated.

Laurent

Comment: Îf you indeed run 14.04, you should download the sources (Last download from here https://www.freefilesync.org/download.php) and compile it. There is also a ppa here https://launchpad.net/~freefilesync/+archive/ubuntu/ffs. but it is not maintained at the moment.

Comment: Also you can get FFS from [getdeb.net repository](http://www.getdeb.net/app/FreeFileSync). But this repository contains updates for many other packages, so be careful.

Comment: Thanks all for your responses. I used the one from Bruni.